Difference between Standort and Aufenthaltsort
WordReference translates both as position/location:

https://www.wordreference.com/deen/Aufenthaltsort
https://www.wordreference.com/deen/standort

The only difference is "Aufenthaltsort" has an additional meaning of "place of residence". Is there any difference when they mean position/location?
DWDS mentions only the "place of residence" definition, but I'm more interested when it's used for things, which don't have a place of residence.
For instance, I have seen the following text in https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/asien/libanon-hisbollah-pager-102.html:

Dass eine Miliz wie die Hisbollah in großem Stil Pager verwendet, hat wohl einen einfachen Grund: Anders als bei Handys oder Smartphones kann ihr Aufenthaltsort nicht ermittelt werden.

Would this sentence have a different meaning if "Standort" was used instead?

Based on the examples I'm seeing, the DWDS entry is incomplete and "place of residence" (Wohnort) isn't even the most common meaning. For example one example given is "Wenn ein Trainingskontrollsystem funktionieren soll, muss von den Athleten die ständige Meldung ihres Aufenthaltsortes erwartet werden:" I'm pretty sure athletes aren't expected to report their place of residence all the time, more like their whereabouts at the moment. Perhaps the definition in German Wiktionary would be more helpful: "der Ort, wo jemand sich ständig oder vorübergehend befindet."

The definition for "Aufenthaltsort" in German Wiktionary, according to @RDBury in a comment is:

der Ort, wo jemand sich ständig oder vorübergehend befindet.

Without having checked it (I trust RDBury :-) ) I think the definition is a good one.
"Standort" is derived from "stehen" (to stand). The "Standort" (verbatim: "place of standing") is the place where a person/something literally stands. In short, to have a "Standort" something must be able to stand somewhere. Otherwise the word must be capable of being used as a "metonymy"1). For example, a company might have a "Standort": the location (or one of the locations) of its office, its workshops or the like.
Notice, though, that "stehen" and "to stand" have different meanings: "stehen" - in German, unlike English - doesn't include the concept of moving around. In English, a house is located somewhere, in German it stands - without any chance of ever going away. German "stehen" is a static thing, while English "to stand" is a mode of moving around, like "to go", "to run", etc..
The "Aufenthaltsort", on the other hand, is constructed the same way, but from "Aufenthalt" (whereabouts). To have an "Aufenthaltsort" the something sporting it must be capable of changing it, because "aufhalten" (the verb from which "Aufenthalt is derived) includes the concept of being temporary and being changeable, whereas "stehen" (see above) does not.
So, while the company from above may have a "Standort" it cannot have an "Aufenthaltsort", because that would implicitly mean that the company is able to change it on short notice. My purse, on the other hand, doesn't have a "Standort", because it cannot stand (only lie about), but it has an "Aufenthaltsort" - and I would really, really like to know where that is.

1) The use of a phrase in a certain figurative meaning. e.g. "the White House decided" (in fact not the house decided anything but the one person everybody knows lives there: the president of the United States). see Wikipedia for details.

Quote: »English "to stand" is a mode of moving around« Really? I never heard someone say »I stand into the living room« or »Next week I must stand to Berlin.« Please give me some examples in which the verb »to stand« is used to describe a movement.

'My purse, on the other hand, doesn't have a "Standort", because it cannot stand (only lie about), but it has an "Aufenthaltsort" - and I would really, really like to know where that is.' - I kind of disagree here. You may argue it is, strictly speaking, incorrect or contradictory in some way, but common contemporary usage uses "Standort" for very temporary locations, such as your current location while navigating through a city. One could say it is a very literal meaning of "to stand", as it refers e.g. to your car "standing" on the ground in some place at this very moment, even though ...

... it will have moved on just a second later. Accordingly, terms like "Standortermittlung" are set terms by now, even though they virtually exclusively refer to things that might change their location (even frequently), for you typically do not need to locate something static the way that "Standortermittlung" is used for.

@HubertSchölnast: I have explained what I meant by that des langen und des breiten (the long and the broad way) in the paragraphs before that and if you are not going to understand (notice: no movement involved there either) then no example will change that. But since you insist, here is an analogy: "zero" is a "number" even though it describes the absence of things - "zero pieces of cake" means no cake at all - piece of cake, no?

@bakunin: In the paragraph before you claimed, that the English verb to stand includes the concept of moving around. I think that this is wrong. I think that the English verb to stand does not include the concept of moving around. But maybe I'm wrong. I want to learn. If you can use to stand in a sense where it includes the concept of moving around, then there must be a valid English sentence that makes use of the verb to stand to describe a movement. I just asked you for an example for that so that I can learn from you. But instead you just write an answer that sounds unfriendly.

@HubertSchölnast: far be it from me to even sound, much less be unfriendly, so here again: "moving" as a concept involves also the absence of moving. "Verbs of motion" include "to stand", "to go", "to lie", "to fly", .... and while the English "to stand" just means the literal act of standing - "I stand", but NOT "the potted plant stands on the table" - the German "stehen" does incorporate figurative meanings aside from a (null-)motion: "ich stehe" but also "die Topfpflanze steht auf dem Tisch". The English "to stand" is a null-motion, but still a motion, just like "zero" is an amount.

@HubertSchölnast: ...furthermore: "to fly" is also a "verb of motion" although the person flying usually doesn't move - only the plane does.


der Aufenthaltsort
der Ort, an dem sich jemand auf(ent)hält
whereabouts; the place where someone is
The verb »(sich) aufenthalten« did exist in German language, but has become outdated and is no longer part of modern German. It was replaced by »(sich) aufhalten«. The phrase »sich an einem Ort aufhalten« means »to be at a place«. The noun »Aufenthaltsort« was derived from the verb »(sich) aufenthalten« before it has become extinct, so it means »the place where someone is«.
In many contexts »to be somewhere« has the meaning »to live somewhere«, and therefore »Aufenthaltsort« often has the meaning »residence, domicile, place of living«. But »Aufenthaltsort« can also be used if a person is located at a certain place just for a few minutes. If you really mean place of living, then »Wohnort« is the better choice, because it exactly means »place of living« and nothing else.
Note, that »Aufenthaltsort« is »the place where someone is«. It usually is not »the place where something is«. The verb »(sich) aufhalten« is used for persons only (rarely also for other person-like beings like animals, ghosts, gods, robots etc.) but not for things that can't decide on their own where to go to. So usually you don't use Aufenthaltsort or sich aufhalten for a pager or a phone, but for the person wearing it. But in the example you found Aufenthaltsort is still clearly used for the device; maybe because it is so closely connected to the person who wears it. (Another possible reason is discussed later.)

der Standort
der Ort, an dem jemand/etwas steht
the place, where someone/something stands
You can use Standort for both people and things, so at first glance it looks like the better choice to describe the location of a pager. But there is another problem: The noun »Standort« is derived from the verb »stehen« which means »to stand«. So you can use »Standort« only for things that stand. But a pager does not stand. It usually hangs on the belt of its wearer or it lays on a table.
So, while »Standort« is generally suitable for devices, it still can't be used for wearables.
Additional info: In German the verb »stehen« is also used for buildings:

Im Wald steht eine Hütte. In der Stadt stehen viele Wolkenkratzer.
There is a hut in the forest. There are many skyscrapers in the city.

For that reason, also a company, that is located in a building, also has a Standort.

Position
position
In my opinion this word is the best choice to describe the place of a thing that is not standing. So, I would have written the sentence in question in this version:

Dass eine Miliz wie die Hisbollah in großem Stil Pager verwendet, hat wohl einen einfachen Grund: Anders als bei Handys oder Smartphones kann ihre Position nicht ermittelt werden.

But still there are some tiny issues with »Position«:
The first issue is, that it is a loanword that doesn't really sound German (it was imported from Latin in the 16th century). This really isn't a big problem, because most people don't care about that, but some people still prefer words with a more German sound.
The other issue is, that »Position« has a very generic meaning. It can be used for anything and everybody. German native speakers have a tendency to use more specific synonyms, especially when it comes to describe the kind of being located. In English you normally just say »something is somewhere«. You can do that in German too (etwas ist irgendwo), but we love to replace »ist« with a more specific verb of location (liegen, sitzen, stehen, hängen, stecken). Maybe this was the reason, why the author decided not to use »ihre Position« but »ihr Standort«.


